# Sharepoint reports showing up as xml

Tags: reporting-services, reports, report-viewer

We recently installed PowerPivot into our SharePoint environment and it started causing issues with our reports(.rdl) which are now displaying as XML.

Any ideas what might cause this?

Answer (score 2):

This was a result of the Report Server Addin somehow being removed from the server. A re-install of this add-in resolved the issues.